# Not able to call Redis lua script for hmget from java

Tags: java, lua, redis, lua-scripting-library

I am new to Redis.Please find the below redis lua script using which returns value from using redis hmget command.I am doing a nil check.If the value is not nil return the value which is retrived from redis pcall else return none.

```
public static final String LOAD_PARAMS_LUA_SCRIPT = local jobType = redis.pcall('hmget',KEYS[1],KEYS[2]) if jobType ~= nil then return jobType  else jobType = 'none' end;
```

I am invoking the lua script from java as below:

```
    List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("1000.123","status"); 
    List<String> args = Arrays.asList(); 
    if(!this.connection.scriptExists(LOAD_PARAMS_LUA_SCRIPT)) {
                    this.connection.scriptLoad(LOAD_PARAMS_LUA_SCRIPT);
    }

ArrayList<String> test = (ArrayList<String>)connection.eval(GET_BULK_JOB_PARAMS_LUA_SCRIPT, keys, args);
            System.out.println("test:" + test);
```

Please let me know if am missing anything.The response which i get everytime is null.

Comment: works fine for me on raw redis. maybe the keys are wrong?

Comment: Is the invocation from java correct?

Comment: @cmhai I don't know the exact client you're using, but in general it looks okay. what happens if you run the script manually?

Comment: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'eval' command

Comment: it should be `EVAL "<your_script>" 2 <key1> <key2>`. works for me

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/pwDYw1cK

Comment: working now.Had missed the semicolon after end.Thanks :)

Comment: It's actually not needed :)